# jQuery dependent script ignores $in_footer bool and doesn't work in header

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin uses the following to enqueue script in jQuery dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug, plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.js', '', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

If I use it on child theme where I dequeue default WordPress jQuery and load jQuery from CDN in footer, both jQuery and my script land in footer and it works correctly.

Unfortunately when I use plugin on default theme, where default WordPress jQuery is loaded in header, `$in_footer` is ignored, script appears in header after jQuery and doesn't work despite no errors in console.

I wouldn't like to replace default jQuery or even move it to the footer, because it can break other things for users.

My script is the following, `phpVars` is properly passed in localized script, above in generated HTML:

```
var timeout;

jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout);        
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, phpVars.acau_update_delay );
});
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently jQuery dependence makes no difference, if I specify an empty array instead, plugin script is still loaded in header below jQuery and doesn't work, this time only with version parameter instead of both version and jQuery `?ver%5B0%5D=jquery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about poor typo, I put one extra parameter `''` before dependency parameter:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug, plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.js', '', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

should be:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug, plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

Now my script properly loads in footer.